# Html list add textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I need your help I want to put a little textbox every time I add an ingredient to the list. Just next to it so i can put the quantity. Can somebody help me ?
Here is the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Ingredient</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/recetas.js">  </script>  

<body>
    <label for="receta">Nombre Receta:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="receta" value="" maxlength="20" /><br>

<h1>INGREDIENTES</h1>
<ul>

</ul>
<select onchange="selectIngredient(this);">
    <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
    <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
</select>
<button>GUARDAR</button>    
<li><a href="resumen.html" data-transition="none" rel="external">testing2</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the js that i dont know how to change so i can put the textbox:

```
    function selectIngredient(select)
        { 
          var $ul = $(select).closest('.ui-select').prev('ul');
    console.log($ul[0])
      if ($ul.find('input[value=' + $(select).val() + ']').length == 0) {
        console.log('s')
            $ul.append('<li onclick="$(this).remove();">' +
              '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
              $(select).val() + '" /> ' +
              $(select).find('option:selected').text() + '</li>');
      }
        }
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is fix your invalid HTML.

Comment: Specifically all the content tags (divs, buttons, etc) should be inside the body tag.  The div after the body element is also never closed.

Comment: I dont understand my html works fine.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i understood right, but what i saw in your code is the input hidden and the remove on the list. I remove the hidden property and put the name of the ingredient on an span to set there the remove function and i set an id to the ul named ingredientes.

Here's the code:

```
$("#addIng").change(function(){
      var $ul = $("#ingredientes");
console.log($ul[0])
  if ($ul.find('input[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').length == 0) {
    console.log('s')
        $ul.append('<li>' +
          '<input name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
          $(this).val() + '" /> <span onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">' +
          $(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</span></li>');
      }

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jorgehdez/UXsjd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your html that makes it strange but just to answer your question and help you keep working on.

```
function selectIngredient(select)
{ 
  var ul = $("ul");
  if (ul.find('input[value=' + $(select).val() + ']').length == 0) 
  {
    var li = '<li><input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + $(select).val() + '" /> ' + $(select).find('option:selected').text() + '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" />' + '<a onclick="$(this).parent().remove();"> Remove </a> </li>';
    ul.append(li);
  }
}
```

This should work, however you should give a id or class to your list, so it would be easier to find it, this code will add a item to every list in the whole page.

I hope it helps you anyway.